# How to make add to cart page using reactjs and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api, redux-toolkit

1. not getting quantity
2. whenever i push a product inside a cart, the product has been duplicated,
3. in single product page, if i add a cart then "add to cart" should be change into "go to cart"

```
this is my cartSlice page.

const CartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    add(state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },

    remove(state, action) {
      return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload);
    },
  },
});

this is my singleProduct page

const SingleProduct = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data: products } = useSelector((state) => state.product);
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const product = products.find((product) => String(product.id) === productId);

  const handleAdd = (product) => {
    dispatch(add(product));
  };

  return (
    <section className={style.SingleProductSection}>
          <div className={style.btns}>
            <button
              className={style.addToCart}
              onClick={() => {
                handleAdd(product);
              }}
            >
              <FaCartPlus />
              <span>Add to cart</span>
            </button>
            <Link to="/buyNow">
              <button className={style.buyNow}>
                <AiFillThunderbolt /> <span>Buy Now</span> {/* buy now page */}
              </button>
            </Link>
          </div>
  );
};

here is my cart page

const Cart = () => {
  const [total, setTotal] = useState();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const carts = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const handleRemove = (productId) => {
    return dispatch(remove(productId));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTotal(
      carts.reduce(
        (acc, curr) => acc + Number(curr.price.toString().split(".")[0]),
        0
      )
    );
  }, [carts]);

  return (
    <>
    
          {carts.map((product) => {
            return (
              <div className={style.product_cart} quantity={product.quantity}>
                <img
                  src={product.image}
                  alt="product_image"
                  className={style.product_image}
                />
                <p className={style.product_title}>
                  {product.title.substring(0, 18)}...
                </p>
                <p className={style.product_price}>
                  ₹{product.price.toString().split(".")[0]}
                </p>

                <div className={style.product_quantity}>
                  <button className="decrement">-</button>
                  <p>{/* {quantity} */}0</p>
                  <button className="increment">+</button>
                </div>

                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    handleRemove(product.id);
                  }}
                >
                  <AiFillDelete className={style.product_delete_icon} />
                </button>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>

        <div className={style.cartItem_2}>
          <p className={style.product_total}>
            <span>Total :</span>
            &nbsp;
            <strong>₹{total}</strong>
          </p>
          <div className={style.cart_buyNow}>
            <Link to="/buyNow">
              <button className={style.buyNow}>
                <AiFillThunderbolt /> <span>Buy Now</span> {/* buy now page */}
              </button>
            </Link>
          </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

1. not getting quantity
2. whenever i push a product inside a cart, the product has been duplicated,
3. in single product page, if i add a cart then "add to cart" should be change into "go to cart"
   not able to solve this problem,

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure that these are the exact causes but hopefully these points will help a bit.

1. not getting quantity - try using `product.quantity` here instead of just `quantity`

```
<button className="decrement">-</button>
<p>{/* {quantity} */}0</p> // <-- change here
<button className="increment">+</button>
```

2. whenever i push a product inside a cart, the product has been duplicated - you don't want to mutate the store in redux, so try this (`remove` is fine):

```js
add(state, action) {
  return [...state, action.payload];
},
```

3. add to cart/go to cart - you could do something like use a piece of state to track if the user has clicked add, if they haven't, do one thing, if they have, do another:

```js
const SingleProduct = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data: products } = useSelector((state) => state.product);
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const product = products.find((product) => String(product.id) === productId); 
  // addition
  const [hasClickedAdd, setHasClickedAdd] = useState(false)
  // addition

  const handleAdd = (product) => {
    dispatch(add(product));
    // addition
    setHasClickedAdd(true);
    // addition
  };

  return (
    <section className={style.SingleProductSection}>
          <div className={style.btns}>
            <button
              className={style.addToCart}
              onClick={() => {
                handleAdd(product);
              }}
            >
              <FaCartPlus />
              // addition
              <span>{hasClickedAdd ? 'Buy now' : 'Add to cart'}</span>
              // addition
            </button>
            <Link to="/buyNow">
              <button className={style.buyNow}>
                <AiFillThunderbolt /> <span>Buy Now</span> {/* buy now page */}
              </button>
            </Link>
          </div>
  );
};
```

nb, if you do this, you're probably also going to want to change the click handler so that clicking on the 'Buy now' text doesn't just add another one to the cart